# How to determine ETH price of ERC20 token using my own full node?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, nodes, price

So I have a contract address of an ERC20 token and I have direct access to a full node.
I want to determine the price of that token in ETH without making any external API calls and just by using my own full node.

How do I go about doing that?

Can I just divide the amount of ETH owned by the contract to the amount of tokens minted?

Comment: The price is not a global constant, it can vary from one exchange to another (CEX or DEX), including between versions of the same exchange or different pools of the same tokens pair. [Here](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/v3/guides/quoting) the documentation of how to get the qotes in UniswapV3, using their SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do it, as *Rafael* say that depend of the **Router** address of ERC20 Token you need call the price with a **web3** files like Javascrypt. pretty easy to get current price of token ask if you want an example ..

Just **replace** url of endpoint with your own node url